# Wine + PlayOnLinux + Amazon kindle

Tags: playonlinux

When I install Amazon Kindle in PlayonLinux, the fonts are not displaying properly, all seems to be like boxes. How to fix it?

Linux Flavour: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed `corefonts` via PlayonLinux?  This would be done with `winetricks` if you were using `wine` directly.  PlayonLinux could have brought this in, but you should double check to confirm.

Have you installed the Ubuntu packages needed for Microsoft fonts?

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem following these:

1. Select Kindle in the PlayOnLinux app
2. Click on the configure icon at the top
3. **Change the Wine Version to 3.0** from the dropdown (if you cannot see it, install Wine 3.0 first!)
4. Create a desktop shortcut from PlayOnLinux
5. Copy the `.desktop` file and paste it in `usr/share/applications` using administrative privileges